# Avoiding Spaghetti Code

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I've been reading how to [avoid spaghetti code in batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/goto.php).

In the example of what spaghetti code is, I realized that the batch file that I use when I logon almost fits this example. Could someone please help me make my batch file not have spaghetti code?

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS


:MENU
echo Welcome %USERNAME%

echo 1 - Start KeePass
echo 2 - Backup
echo 3 - FireFox
echo 4 - Exit

SET /P M=Please Enter Selection, then Press Enter:

IF %M%==1 GOTO StarKeePass
IF %M%==2 GOTO Backup
IF %M%==3 GOTO FireFox
IF %M%==4 GOTO :EOF
GOTO MENU


:StarKeePass
SET keePass="%USERPROFILE%\KeePass\KeePass-2.30\KeePass.exe"
SET kdb="%USERPROFILE%\KeePass\PasswordDatabase\PasswordDatabase.kdbx"

echo I'll start KeePass for You
START "" %keePass% %kdb%

GOTO MENU

:Backup
SET backup="%USERPROFILE%\backup.bat"
call %backup%

GOTO MENU

:FireFox
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\"
start firefox.exe

GOTO MENU
```

Comment: This is definitively not Spaghetti-code. It is called SC for example when function calls are syntactically nested too deep or other constructs, which should be logically grouped and split into multiple lines.

Comment: @Ctx - Thanks for the clarification. So, from the looks of things, it's fine, correct? I have another post about how to make it more robust, but that's a different question.

Comment: Looks fine to me, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, if you want to use subroutines you should do this:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS


:MENU
echo Welcome %USERNAME%

echo 1 - Start KeePass
echo 2 - Backup
echo 3 - FireFox
echo 4 - Exit

SET /P M=Please Enter Selection, then Press Enter:

IF %M%==1 CALL :StartKeePass
IF %M%==2 CALL :Backup
IF %M%==3 CALL :FireFox
IF %M%==4 GOTO :EOF
GOTO MENU


:StartKeePass
SET "keePass=%USERPROFILE%\KeePass\KeePass-2.30\KeePass.exe"
SET "kdb=%USERPROFILE%\KeePass\PasswordDatabase\PasswordDatabase.kdbx"

echo I'll start KeePass for You
START "" %keePass% %kdb%

GOTO :EOF

:Backup
SET "backup=%USERPROFILE%\backup.bat"
call %backup%

GOTO :EOF

:FireFox
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\"
start firefox.exe

GOTO :EOF
```

Note that I changed a few things. Instead of goto... goto menu, you should use `call :label` `goto :eof`/ `exit /b`. Besides that, you had a spelling error Star**t**KeePass, and instead of `set variable="value"`, it's better to use `set "variable=value"`. This will also accept spaces in the value, but it won't add quotes to your variable

Next time you should probably post this to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), because these things aren't really errors

Comment: quick question, why is it better to say goto: eof than goto: menu?

Comment: to explain it, call temporarily gives creates a new batch-file inside this one, starting at the given label. When that batch-file is finished, it goes back to the calling one, at the line under the calling line.

Comment: goto :eof isn't really better, but it's a choice to work with subroutines, or just constantly goto positions in a batch-file. I suggest looking [here](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) for a better explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to remove `goto`s altogether, you can simply call the script again to keep using it. Also, look into the [choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command if you're using a version of Windows later than XP, since it will eliminate the need to check if the user entered invalid input.

```
@echo off

cls
echo Welcome %USERNAME%

echo 1 - Start KeePass
echo 2 - Backup
echo 3 - FireFox
echo 4 - Exit

choice /C:1234 /M "Please enter your selection: " /N

:: The first option listed by choice's /C option will return an errorlevel value of 1, the second 2, and so on
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
    SET keePass="%USERPROFILE%\KeePass\KeePass-2.30\KeePass.exe"
    SET kdb="%USERPROFILE%\KeePass\PasswordDatabase\PasswordDatabase.kdbx"

    echo I'll start KeePass for You
    START "" %keePass% %kdb%
)

:: I've converted these to one-liners simply for personal preference.
:: You can keep these the way you had them if you put them inside of parentheses like with option 1.
if %errorlevel% equ 2 call "%USERPROFILE%\backup.bat"
if %errorlevel% equ 3 start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
if %errorlevel% equ 4 exit /b

:: Calls this script again, simulating a goto :MENU
:: Personally, I'd stick with a label and a goto in this instance,
:: but this is how you could do it if you don't want to use goto at all
call %0
```

If each choice the user can make is fairly simple (i.e. it can be simplified to one or two commands), you might want to code this way; otherwise, definitely use subroutines like Dennis suggested.

Answer (score 0):

My take on organizing this, added a reset to `m` variable, allowed some accidental input to be dealt with, and made it all checked in one block of code.

Nothing wrong with 'Dennis van Gils' answer, figured i would show you a different approach.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:menu
set "m="
cls
echo/Welcome !username!
echo/
echo/1 - Start keepass
echo/2 - Backup
echo/3 - Firefox
echo/4 - Exit
echo/
set /p "m=Please enter selection, then press enter:"
if not defined m (
    cls
    echo/Error: Empty input.
    pause
) else (
    if "!m!" equ "1" (
        set "keepass=!userprofile!\keepass\keepass-2.30\keepass.exe"
        set "kdb=!userprofile!\keepass\passworddatabase\passworddatabase.kdbx"
        echo/I'll start keepass for you
        start "" !keepass! !kdb!
    ) else (
        if "!m!" equ "2" (
            set "backup=!userprofile!\backup.bat"
            call !backup!
        ) else (
            if "!m!" equ "3" (
                cd "c:\program files (x86)\mozilla firefox\"
                start firefox.exe
            ) else (
                if "!m!" equ "4" (
                    goto :eof
                ) else (
                    cls
                    echo/Error: ["!m!"] not recognized.
                    pause
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
goto :menu
```

Note: `echo/` is used as a habit, as `echo:` and `echo\` i mistake for parts of a file path/url, and `echo.` is so painstakingly noted for its longer command time.

Also, i prefer using `!` over `%` along with `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` by pure preference, and ease of block coding.